# How to access $scope variable in controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hello I am having problems accessing the value of my $scope.searchText. It keeps saying that it is undefined.

In my html page I have the following. (the {{searchText}} updates normally when I make changes.

```
<label>Filter: {{searchText}}
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="searchText"
           ng-change="testingChange()" placeholder="Search Projects" />
</label>
```

and in my controller it is initialized as:

```
$scope.searchText;
$scope.testingChange = function () {
    $scope.testArr = itContains(vm.projects, $scope.searchText);
    console.log($scope.searchText); //prints undefined.
    console.log($scope.testArr.length);
}
```

but as mentioned before, when I try to do console.log($scope.searchText) it shows undefined.

I am trying to return an answer based on the that variable. How do I access it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: show us the code

Comment: I made some changed and I undid the code part. Sorry.

Comment: post your whole controller code and HTML

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/iYwBEyNENecavETQK00t

Comment: It is initialized as an empty string, but isn't it supposed to change when it is changed in the html side?

Comment: @RonnyPacheco : Please fix your plunkr.

Comment: New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved.

Comment: Would the searchText variable be in a parent or child? How do I access them?

@georgeawg

Comment: This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of [always have a '.' in your `ng-models`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) – watch 3 minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with `ng-switch`.